# How to find one of several strings via grep?

Tags: grep

I want to find files which contains one of the several strings. Here is example:

```
grep -e "max|min" <<< "emaxxmin" #it prints nothing
grep -e "min" <<< "emaxxmin" #it works
grep -e "max" <<< "emaxxmin" #it works
```

I confuses me a little bit. In my opinion regular expression is correct (it uses "choice" operator). man command also mentions about special treatment of `|` symbol

Comment: Use `-E` instead of `-e`

Comment: `grep` by default uses the BRE regex flavour where `\|` is the alternation operator. switch to its ERE flavour with flag `-E` if you want to use `|` as the alternation operator

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this:

```
grep -E '(max|min)' <<< "emaxxmin"
```

Or, with basic posix regular expressions:

```
grep '\(max\|min\)' <<< "emaxxmin"
```

Or, with the use of the `-e` argument (probably the simplest solution here?):

```
grep -e max -e min <<< "emaxxmin"
```

Comment: Thanks, I mixed up `e` argument. I though it enabled extended format

Comment: @LmTinyToon Gotcha. Interestingly, `-e` can really be used here. But in a different meaning as you had in mind. Added an example with `-e`, for more information on `-e` check `man grep` if you like